# Terraform - Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use terraform to create a model on SageMaker by following [this page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sagemaker_model)
I can't assign a full access policy to the sagemaker role due to permission constrains, so I created a role and attached a policy with part of the permissions

When I tested `Terraform plan`, it gave me this:

```
Error: Invalid template interpolation value
...
```

```
..........................
 141:                 "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy"
 142:             ],
 143:             "Resource": [
 144:                 "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.xx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxx_bucket}",
 145:                 "arn:aws:s3:::${local.binaries_bucket_name}",
 146:                 "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.xx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxx_bucket}/*",
 147:                 "arn:aws:s3:::${local.binaries_bucket_name}/*",
 148:                 "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:*:repository/*",
 149.....................
 157:         }
 158:     ]
 159: }
 160: POLICY
    |----------------
    | aws_s3_bucket.xx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxx_bucket is object with 25 attributes

Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

I'm new to this, just wondering if this is complaining the bucket name is too long or something else? What should I do to fix this, I'm a bit confused. Many thanks.

(PS: Terraform version `v0.13.4` + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws `v3.20.0`)

Comment: "around 60 lines of different permissions" - can you provide compelt, ready for copy-and-paste evaluation code?

Comment: @Marcin Hi I've added all the permissions, hopefully now can reproduce this error.

Comment: Have you checked @Matt's answer? It is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears what you want here is the ARN of the S3 bucket, which is provided by [exported resource attributes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/blocks/resources/behavior.html#accessing-resource-attributes). Specifically, you probably want the `arn` resource attribute.

Updating your policy like:

```
 144:             "${aws_s3_bucket.xx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxx_bucket.arn}",
 146:             "${aws_s3_bucket.xx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxx_bucket.arn}/*",
```

will provide you with the String that you need by accessing the `arn` attribute. The currently written policy is accessing `aws_s3_bucket.xx_xxxxxxxxxx_xxx_bucket`, which is a Map (possibly Object) of every argument and attribute for that resource, and will not interpolate within the string of your policy.

Comment: Hi I tried this, the error disappeared, but when I look at the created policy, these two lines became like this:```arn:aws:s3:::arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxxxxxxx",  "arn:aws:s3:::arn:aws:s3:::xxxxxxxx/*"```

Comment: The `````arn:aws:s3:::` duplicated for some reason....

Comment: @Cecilia Ensure that my answer is used verbatim in your policy, and then the duplication will disappear. The duplication exists due to modification from my answer.

Comment: My bad, it works now, thank you sooo much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a custom policy correctly then link it to the bucket, you can see here some examples:
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/JousP/s3-bucket-policy/aws/latest/examples/custom-policy